# Unique magic triplets

Tags: code-golf, array

### Description

Your input is a list of integers \$[a_1, \dots, a_n]\$.

A **magic triplet** is a triplet \$(a_i, a_j, a_k)\$ of values from this list, such that

- the indices \$\{i, j, k\}\$ are all distinct,
- the values are in ascending order (\$a_i \leq a_j \leq a_k\$), and
- the sum of two of the values equals the third.

Your task is to output all *unique* magic triplets, in any order.

### Rules

1. Each number in the input list is guaranteed to be in the range \$-2^{32} \leq a < 2^{32}\$.
2. The input list's length is guaranteed to be at most 1000.
3. The input list's length may be less than 3 (even 0). In this case, there are no magic triplets, and your program should produce an empty result.
4. The shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
[1,2,3,2,4] -> [[1,2,3], [1,3,4], [2,2,4]]
[0,0,0,0] -> [[0,0,0]]
[1,0,-1] -> [[-1,0,1]]
[1,2] -> []
[1,2,4,8,99] -> []
[33,90,7,24,60,32,80,43,15,40,36,90,65,12,91,33,88,1,96,33,40] -> [[7,33,40], [32,33,65], [1,32,33], [1,90,91], [7,36,43], [24,36,60], [12,24,36], [36,60,96], [15,65,80], [40,40,80]]
```

#### Notes

- In the second test case, `[[0,0,0], [0,0,0]]` is not a valid answer. No triplet may be listed twice in the output.
- Remember that your program may order the triplets differently. For example, `[[2,2,4], [1,2,3], [1,3,4]]` is also a valid output for the first test case.
- Nonetheless, `[[4,2,2], …]` is invalid: each triplet *itself* must be in ascending order.

Comment: Hey @chaugiang, I rewrote your question for clarity, and to be a bit more in the codegolf.SE “style”.  If you disagree with my rewrite, feel free to roll it back (or fix what you dislike about it).

Comment: @Lynn Thank you a lot for your contributions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>46 51</s> 58 bytes

```ruby
->l{l.permutation(3).select{|a,b,c|a+b==c}.map(&:sort)|[]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU/LCoMwEPyVnIrSjRhjrSnYH5EcVBQKsYqPQzF@u52oLYHs7MzsJDvM5Wdrso0/zWKCvh7aeSqmV/f2pB@MtamrabEFlVTZ4lpmWbUGbdF7l8fYDZNvc71uOcsFsYiY3O9Y068/0Z@IiaXElAIhYVYhsTsE0AmghCNFjSGJG6rjksOWoBfQFYLcaIocQJUcbRwikoPgzrO/AhaicPmY5@5XIR1HHOYTSALmkdZuscUa27MmN9jrCw)

Ok, not so straightforward, but now seems to work.

Comment: I'm afraid this works only for input array already sorted ascending, which is not guaranteed by the challenge. For example from test case E it finds only 5 sets while 10 are expected.

Comment: You are right. Fixed now.

Comment: Yepp, that was the easy fix. But handling negative numbers like in test case B `[1, 0, -1]` may be harder. ☹

Comment: Oops. Fixed again.

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>11</s> <s>10</s> <s>9</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
{æ3ùêʒxsOå
```

+1 byte as bugfix for test cases like `[1,0,-1] → [[-1,0,1]] (-1+1=0)` and `[-1,-2,-3] → [[-3,-2,-1]] (-1+-2=-3)`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/@vAy48M7D686Nami2P/w0v//ow11FIx0FIzBpImOgi6Qrwtk6hrHAgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##RU2xDcIwEFwlSn2W/P6PsauMwACRC5AoqCgiISJEywDZAQo2oHbHGCxi3gQJvV5/p7u/O4yb7X5XjlPfNu/r3LT9VM75zvmZH6/5NK7zrVxQhoHgwLqS0CixMLQg9zsQBMRYGTOixQpO4C3YIVgIgzqIUl9F34EcIkG9IYAQfYVi678hGBU1j@FBGqR132KLZehvM5zSBw).

**Explanation:**

```python
{           # Sort the (implicit) input-list from lowest to highest value
 æ          # Take the powerset of this sorted list
  3ù        # Only keep inner lists of length 3
    ê       # (Sort and) uniquify this entire list of triplets
     ʒ      # Filter this list of (individually sorted) triplets by:
      x     #  Double each value in the triplet (without popping the triplet itself)
       s    #  Swap to get the original triplet
        O   #  Take the sum of this triplet
         å  #  And check whether this value is in the doubled list
            # (after which the filtered list is output implicitly as result)
```

The last four bytes could alternatively be `œÆ0å` (given by *@Grimy*): [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/@vAy48M7D686Neno5MNtBoeX/v8fbaijYKSjYAwmTXQUdIF8XSBT1zgWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##RU0xCgIxEPzKcfUEdrO5mFT3kCOFgoWVhSAcYnsPON@ghT@wDjY@w4/EjSfIsuwMMzuzP6w3u205jn3bvKe5afuxnPJN8iPfX/PzkifK13JGGQaGhei6hEYJwfCC7O/AISDGykQQCStYB08Qi0BwAu7glPoq@g5sERnqDQGM6Ct0VP8Nw6ioeQIP1iCt@xYTluG/zUhKHw).

```python
      œ     #  Get all possible permutations of the triplet
       Æ    #  Reduce each by subtracting: [a,b,c] → a-b-c
        0å  #  And check if there are any 0s among the reduced permutations
```

Comment: `xsOå` can also be `œÆP>`. Same byte-count, but more stylish.

Comment: @Grimmy The `Æ` was also in my 9-byter. :) I've added it (with `0å` instead of `P>`, since it's a bit more logical to me what's being checked). PS: It might be more stylish, but I think that permutations builtin would decrease the performance slightly, though. :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
Ṣœc3ḤiSƊƇQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU49DsIgFL7KGxwfCQgiHMM4NQ2TcdD0Aq4uTRx1cW4cPYCdm/YeeBH8KGpIeN/f@@C4b5pTSrHvxttOx9fjsJ0uU7tJQzteY39fvM/PKqWaasW0ZNLzbQL/@Bf9BcPkmLyHoBH2kmkNA7IF1Eg4TANLrTCzZkvMgiv4HkV51aEH0NtCjUSlgCByZn4FKkyV@7Ev8q8kl6MChQ8)

```
Ṣ             Sort the input,
 œc3          find all length-3 subsequences,
        Ƈ     filter to only the sets for which
      S       the sum of all three elements
     i        is an element of
    Ḥ  Ɗ      the set with all elements doubled,
         Q    and uniquify.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 11 bytes

```
{o⊇Ṫ.+/₂∈}ᵘ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY0xDsIwEAS/ckqLgTgxxm7gIVEUAQUUSJFooiiiSQGBipIfIFHRgIDf2B8x6wRofHuze@v5ZrZYlet8GbmqCKg/oaCY2t3N1rV5H2xzMc8HxNbcT67K7XFvXtdBbwjbNg3o2bmEEs4oYhS3r0jZb/@qPxCMFCOtAWKEdchoDANYQsZIKEwBi48wPZNdTGLn8DWK/KlCD6SW3SpCVGYAmc@0v4DC5L4f95lIKf0A)

Takes input through the input variable and outputs through the output variable.

```
{        }ᵘ    Output every unique output from:
    .          the output is
  ⊇            a subsequence
   Ṫ           of length 3
{              of the input
 o             sorted
     +         the sum of which
      /₂       divided by 2
        ∈      is an element of
         }     the output.
```

Comment: `[2,2,4]` shouldn't be a magic triplet. I think you can fix by replacing the sort by distinct.

Comment: The challenge spec only requires that the *indices* are distinct, and that the values within the triplet are non-decreasing (although it uses the word "increasing"). Note that the first test case contains two `2`s and expects `[2,2,4]` to be output, and the fifth test case only contains one `2`, so expects `[2,2,4]` to not be output.

Comment: by bad, I didn't read the question properly.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>13</s>  11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
á3 k_r-ÃmÍâ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=4TMga19yLcNtzeI&input=W1sxLCAyLCAzLCAyLCA0XSwKIFsxLCAwLCAtMV0sCiBbMSwgMl0sCiBbMSwgMiwgNCwgOCwgOTldLAogWzMzLCA5MCwgNywgMjQsIDYwLCAzMiwgODAsIDQzLCAxNSwgNDAsIDM2LCA5MCwgNjUsIDEyLCA5MSwgMzMsIDg4LCAxLCA5NiwgMzMsIDQwXSwKIFstMSwgLTIsIDksIDgsIDMsIDYsIDE3LCAyMCwgLTRdLAogWzAsIDAsIDAsIDAsIDFdCl0KLVEKLW0)

```
á3 k_r-ÃmÍâ // input as arrays
á3            // all unique permutations
  k_          // save list that..
    r-Ã       // reduced by - from first element
         mÍ   // ==mn   => sort all
              â // remove duplicates
```

Thanks to @Shaggy and @Embodiment of Ignorance for saving 2

Comment: 12 bytes: https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=4TMga19yLcNtbiDi&input=W1sxLCAyLCAzLCAyLCA0XSwKIFsxLCAwLCAtMV0sCiBbMSwgMl0sCiBbMSwgMiwgNCwgOCwgOTldLAogWzMzLCA5MCwgNywgMjQsIDYwLCAzMiwgODAsIDQzLCAxNSwgNDAsIDM2LCA5MCwgNjUsIDEyLCA5MSwgMzMsIDg4LCAxLCA5NiwgMzMsIDQwXSwKIFstMSwgLTIsIDksIDgsIDMsIDYsIDE3LCAyMCwgLTRdLAogWzAsIDAsIDAsIDAsIDFdCl0KLVEKLW0. Using `r-` is very clever!

Comment: [11 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=4TMga19yLcNtzeI&input=W1sxLCAyLCAzLCAyLCA0XSwKIFsxLCAwLCAtMV0sCiBbMSwgMl0sCiBbMSwgMiwgNCwgOCwgOTldLAogWzMzLCA5MCwgNywgMjQsIDYwLCAzMiwgODAsIDQzLCAxNSwgNDAsIDM2LCA5MCwgNjUsIDEyLCA5MSwgMzMsIDg4LCAxLCA5NiwgMzMsIDQwXSwKIFstMSwgLTIsIDksIDgsIDMsIDYsIDE3LCAyMCwgLTRdLAogWzAsIDAsIDAsIDAsIDFdCl0KLVEKLW0)

Comment: @Embodiment of Ignorance thanks, it's been a while since I wanted to use it ! Forgot that sort can be just mn!

Comment: Very nicely done, by the way. I took a quick, uncaffeinated stab at this this morning and ended up around 15 bytes.

Comment: @Shaggy thanks for all the help given!

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>65</s> 64 bytes

```perl6
*.combinations(3)>>.sort.grep({@$_.sum==2*.any}).unique(:as(~*))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5NDoJADIX3nqILYxhSJs4MjiCBeA9DDBowJPIjAwti9Opj0QWyafu99r20zbu7ttUImwJisC6/NtWlrLO@bGrjKJYk3DRdz29d3jrP4/rMzVDFsXR5Vo8vxoe6fAy5c8iM83YZs9HKZCMUcBIIEkF9q5/@yRLVAmdYXvkYYBjOmqKscIuwp0gfQdOoKDug7tNK7KhPmv6daWJB@5AemaxBQEyoJ5xTPYGeRG@pAPlFGtkP)

```perl6
*.combinations(3)               # All the combinations of length 3
                 >>.sort        # Sorted
                        .grep({               }) # Filtered by
                              {@$_.sum==         # The sum is equal to
                                        2*.any   # Double any element
                                                .unique(:as(~*))  # And take the unique lists
```

Comment: Flooring the halved sum adds `(0 0 1)` to the new last test case (`[0,0,0,0,1]`).

Comment: ...actually it adds a bunch of stuff to several test cases. I thought [this](https://tio.run/##VY7PCoJAEIfvPcUcInZlXFzXNi2S3iNCLCyE/JObhwg7B71lL2KjEeZlZ79vZn5MmVRn3WY3mB1hDa0lDkW2T/P4mha5YYqHoTBFdRWnKinZnWVxCfdpZLkNbqYRfz9fwtRZw0Wdp5c6YcvYsIfFebuamPgGR9hKBBdB9a@3@9MuqhEOMJ7y0McgGJyirMBBWFCkh6Dpqyjbp@pRS86pdk5/xzSxpH5Ah3Srvk9MqDscUm2Jtov22ADty8E4vXB@uv0A) might work as a fixed version, but 1. I don't actually know Perl and 2. it's missing `(40 40 80)` from the `[33, 90, 7, 24, 60, 32, 80, 43, 15, 40, 36, 90, 65, 12, 91, 33, 88, 1, 96, 33, 40]` case.

Comment: @UnrelatedString Rolled back to a previous version. That test case was modified later (OP added the second `40`), so I had the old version.

Comment: Ah, makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>118 116</s>  115 bytes

Returns a set.

```javascript
a=>new Set(a.flatMap((x,i)=>a.flatMap((y,j)=>j-i&&~(k=a.indexOf(x+y))&&k-i&&k-j?[x,y,x+y].sort((a,b)=>a-b)+'':[])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/LboMwELz3K3witmIjHCjFlUi/oOqhR8TBSUzFQzgKKIFLf52OoYdKtWTZuzOzs55G3/VwvtXXUfT2YpYqX3R@7M2DfJqR6rDq9Piur5ROvGb58Q8w8wZAI@og@KZtrsO6v5jpo6LTfmYsCFrHtKJ5KyY@c4BlONjbSKnmJ@ckTmy/270WJWNsOdt@sJ0JO/tFK1pITg6cxOudQPD0n484EdJPHTzwr2XCScaJUqVHEmOfgu0LlNClKGOMZHgTUPIZr8PSTZail@AVnN1oBmOUKt3aJPKsEBAIN7N@AyqIpdvn0viCRmvQ7bi0yw8)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                             // a[] = input array
  new Set(                       // create a set:
    a.flatMap((x, i) =>          //   for each value x at position i in a[]:
      a.flatMap((y, j) =>        //     for each value y at position j in a[]:
        j - i &&                 //       if j is not equal to i
        ~(                       //       and the position k
          k = a.indexOf(x + y)   //       of x + y in a[]
        ) &&                     //       is not equal to -1
        k - i &&                 //       and k is not equal to i
        k - j ?                  //       and k is not equal to j:
          [x, y, x + y]          //         build the triplet (x, y, x + y)
          .sort((a, b) => a - b) //         sort it in ascending order
          + ''                   //         and coerce it to a string
        :                        //       else:
          []                     //         yield an empty array
      )                          //     end of inner flatMap()
    )                            //   end of outer flatMap()
  )                              // end of Set()
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>94, 89, 88</s>, 85 bytes

One byte saved thanks to frank.

```python
lambda l:{p for p in combinations(sorted(l),3)if sum(p)/2in p}
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLbboMwDH3nK/yYTKnWAE1JJb6k6wNtQYsEJCKZpq3qtzM7AbXThoD4HF/i48R9hXc7FnNXv819M5yvDfSHm4POTuDAjHCxw9mMTTB29MzbKbRX1nNRcNOB/xiY4685hrl71k12ABPaKVjbezCDw@iX@dL41kMNxwzwOUoBuYAi/suTSORWwPKujIxwI59w/mxjsoBKgNYrW2BNjTl79KJPoVlgWIVriS65w5U4lcIUYol@jdUotcJiaGqVYLk9Zacsa0b/2U6P9m9s6Z8LIJMiycxTS/wulrBFzoPYJEVyZXwbGP9j3th@3Z/KkgBCarfuF4kFkAwtCeyTrjJ6SD0hFUuQxsTEgipNRkdEM6E5VDGSpkNfFbtG8XQH6PQE4BjoLnwbx@JxRoYGww@xbXCTGQPropfzfzioa8r55eLzDw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 78 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
f x=nub[y|y@[a,b,c]<-subsequences$sort x,or[2*z==sum y|z<-y]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVLBioMwEL33K@bQgy5j0RitQoWF3b3tH4hQayMr26prImjpv3cnsUK37W01gTfvvZnJhHzl8lscDpfq2DadgremVl1zWH0MhWhV1dTgOFA2HWxzKUWntrPxPVf56rOSalHCkNT9Lh3P42ua4w6LbOPIfifFTy/qQsil1AkDNl3KXk5JIvsjjOfTxhmz7HLMqxoS2DcLoK/tqlrBEkpIPWTo0@bZveKi@bPHDBcd7wnNnnHIMcI4fpB8H2MX18g4hi76DCMXuY9egJzCUIthgB7D2EPyRhF6GIcacjqSqaaEVLcDQDoFGWqWjBowI2U3CfNcZJ9A9qeaGY40R0PvTmSk3DHzgH@Ff41H3ddXSBNQMuEwuI6lowlSjdjTcK0rcsNSP8KhSaTqJjRFNEkdDB/o3pHx0GloRfoSbk7vcHQYLXMPMyaHUau67RWIoRWFEnt6VNOTBcu8P6ucDDYkCRhmdtpgdUL1XQ2WbV9@AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 38 bytes

```
{?{x@<x}'({z=x+y}.)#x@/:{x~?x}#+!3##x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3BEoIwDER/ZZ0egGHQpim1BR34Gi4cvEY79ddr6iGbZDb7ck6vs9ZjyVuW/SGl6/PnKeO7XAcj@23J8t2kmPHCxkipR9cTHFjLryBYTNS6@ws8IlJawYxkcYfzCBbsEC08g2Z4XUMzwwxySNRuY9R0Cm30dlUkJrWUxQggxegbP9Qf)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 66 bytes

```
ＦＬθＦＬθＦＬθＦ¬⌈⟦⁼ικ⁼ιλ⁼κλ›§θι§θκ›§θκ§θλ⟧«≔Ｅ⟦ικλ⟧§θνη¿∧№η⊘Ση¬№υη⊞υη»Ｉυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/LasMwEEXX8VdoOQNT8CuujVcmlKTQlkCXxgsRK5GwItevECj9dlfCizTQRXY6ukeaOwfJ@0PL9Twf257BmzCnUUKHyB7ij3aEd35V5@kM5Us3cT2AItYgsRvpGzULbXvBR9FDMb6aWlyhI6bs9R9s8H@tudc0YoW2zLe3KoZBnYxt8wWlq2DD6s417kuJubdSRwaFqWHTTmYESWzH9UXU8Gm3kOg0t9eSTu6NnbCfBrlA7v14@17ZbMMHKyDm81yWUUSZT88UxpT4FIWU@hRHFKwptpi4MFlTEFIWkHXTlALKEneM/aqany76Fw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＬθＦＬθＦＬθＦ¬⌈⟦
```

Loop through all triples of indices...

```
⁼ικ⁼ιλ⁼κλ
```

... checking whether the indices are distinct...

```
›§θι§θκ›§θκ§θλ
```

... and that the triplet is in ascending order...

```
⟧«≔Ｅ⟦ικλ⟧§θνη
```

... if so then save the triplet in a variable...

```
¿∧№η⊘Ση¬№υη⊞υη
```

... and if it contains its halved sum and is unique then remember it in a list.

```
»Ｉυ
```

After checking all triplets output the unique magic triplets double-spaced with each triplet member on its own line.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, 225 bytes

```java
import java.util.*;L->{var r=new TreeSet();for(int j,k,a,b,t[],i=L.size();i-->0;)for(j=i;j-->0;)if((k=L.indexOf((a=L.get(i))+(b=L.get(j))))>=0&k!=i&k!=j){Arrays.sort(t=new int[]{a,b,a+b});r.add(Arrays.toString(t));}return r;}
```

Port of [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195847/52210), just twice as long.. >.>

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fVJNb9pAEL3zK6Y5VLtlvLGxQ3FdI/UYKU0O9IY4LGaha8BG6zEtRfx2OjZuExIptrzym3nzdr5yvddevlif7XZXOoKcsarJbtSnBG5voR/EQCXQTwPzAxkvK@uCetlGVxV817Y49gBsQcYtdWbgsYEAP5wxE0OQiQdb0dd79q@MG2uZsPvU46MiTTaDRygghfODNz7utQOXFubXv2ghk2XpBItDjmvUOEeaztCmD6qyfwy7reeN/UQ2rDy1SX6BdinEmkm2WJjfTww0gxXrWSn7Yt6BXPIzTv2P6w@pbY5cHr85pw@VqrgPgtpU@PLp7Nhcrfvzk0yc0ouF6HhUTsjZYiVIyuTkDNWuAJeczklT4a6eb7jCrtB9aRew5X6JS8x0BlpemkWmIhHgAEP@orZF/40@esG1ZfAKYoQjjOOX1jDE2MfPOIhw6GM4wJGPUYjBHUYMh41zeIfBAOMAmTsaYYDxsPmN/Jc6XoAek1g/xCEGLMjpXCXo4@UN3oZ54Zthtz1oKd1CKKVg33Xhee@uVoYnsKuJd6SZxjOnnUBDFK9sldJVa9/LLqfJoSKzVWVNasedp00hbu4b0S9w07@ov8N8qqmjFioTLf0d4a7k0/kv)

**Explanation:**

```java
import java.util.*;       // Required import for the TreeSet and both Arrays
L->{                      // Method with integer-List as parameter & sorted Set as return
  var r=new TreeSet();    //  Result-set, starting uninitialized
                          //  A Set will automatically remove duplicates
                          //  (and a TreeSet will automatically sort, which is irrelevant,
                          //   but it's the same size as a regular HashSet anyway)
  for(int j,k,a,b,t[],    //  Temp integers
      i=L.sisze();i-->0;) //  Loop `i` in the range (input-length, 0]:
    for(j=i;j-->0;)       //   Inner loop `j` in the range (`i`, 0]:
      if((k=L.indexOf((a=L.get(i))
                          //    Set `a` to the `i`'th value in the list
          +(b=L.get(j))   //    Set `b` to the `j`'th value in the list
                          //    And add `a` and `b` together
         ))               //    Set `k` to the index of this sum
           >=0            //    If the index `k` is NOT -1
         &k!=i&k!=j){     //    And `k` is also NOT `i` nor `j`:
        Arrays.sort(t=new int[]{a,b,a+b});
                          //     Create an array `t` with items [a,b,a+b],
                          //     and sort the values of this triplet
        r.add(Arrays.toString(t));}
                          //     Then convert this array to a String,
                          //     and add it to the result-TreeSet
  return r;}              //  After the nested loop: return the result-TreeSet
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 13 bytes

```
{f}csT2T.cSQ3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vzqtNrk4xChELzk40Pj//2gTHQVjHQVDHQUDHQVdw1gA)

Port of the solution thats been floating around.

### How it works

```
{f}csT2T.cSQ3
        .c  3  - All combinations length 3 of...
          SQ   - The sorted input
 f             - Filtered such that...
   csT2        - Half the sum of each combination...
  }    T       - Is an element of the original combination
{              - Remove duplicates
```

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 15 bytes

```
{mSdfqsPTeT.PQ3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vzo3OCWtsDggJDVELyDQ@P//aBMdBWMdBUMdBQMdBV3DWAA)

Less sophisticated solution. Posting it because I think it can be golfed more

### How it works

```
{mSdfqsPTeT.PQ3
           .PQ3 - All 3 element permutations of the input
    f           - Filtered such that
      sPT       - The sum of the first 2 inputs...
     q   eT     - Is equal to the last input
 mSd            - Sort all elements
{               - Remove duplicates
```

Answer (score 1):

#### [JULIA](https://julialang.org/)

A solution w/o external package:

```
F(l)=(n=length(sort!(l));a=Set();
for i=1:n,j=1:n,k=1:n i<j<k&&(v=l[[i,j,k]];sum(v) in 2v)&&push!(a,v)end;
[a...])
```

Not a nice one 115 bytes of code (with 2 extra newlines for readability).

A solution using the non-core package `Combinatorics`:

```
using Combinatorics
H(l)=[Set(v for v in combinations(sort(l),3) if sum(v) in 2v)...]
```

Length 85 bytes (or 84 if you omit the space before the '''if''')
You can [REPLIT](https://repl.it/@czylabsonasa/unique-magic-triplets-codegolfstackexchange) online.

Comment: Welcome to CG&CC! I tried [running your solution online](https://tio.run/##XY49C4MwFEV3f0XGBG4lX1ozdOri3lEcrNSSokkxKv33NpZSqDwevHveGe5j7m0jXus6B@vu5OyHq3XN5EfbhqSkPTtVl9tEF9L5kSzEOtJ@FetdoMGPU5SgmO1ImAe6sM2RC0vTtF6fo3UTLWklIKHi6pqx5Ec5PvPHRCQHsUNyn6FRwJg/rBQMxxFSI@dQEgWHVhAZdIz59swzCAkjEN2igIDJt1NvFdY3), but the `Combinatorics` package doesn't seem to be installed on TIO. I don't think there's any problem with using non-standard libraries so long as you mention them in the language header, but it might be a good idea to also write a solution that can be more easily verified.